# OG Validator Error that I can't quite make sense of

Tags: open-graph-protocol

I'm doing some validation of pages on a website I'm working on, and I'm getting the below error.

> OG Validator Error - Extraneous properties specified: The following
>   properties are specified on the webpage but NOT supported for the
>   specified 'og:type': video:actor, video:duration, video:series,
>   video:tag, video:release_date.

The code is as follows (with some redacted info). The issue that I'm struggling with is that another video page has the exact same code (different content, obviously), but formatted the same way and I'm getting no errors. Thoughts?

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title of Episodes">
<meta property="og:description" content="Watch The Episode (Season #, 
Episode ##) of The Show Name or get episode details on URL.com">
<meta property="og:type" content="video.episode">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://img.url.com/mpx-static/image/11/499/190228_3914928_The_Episode.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1920">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="1080">
<meta property="og:video" content="https://pdk.theplatform.com/current/pdk/swf/flvPlayer.swf?id=player&amp;v=%2F%2Fplayer.theplatform.com%2Fp%2FNnzsPC%2Fwidget%2Fconfig%2Fselect%2Fmedia%2Fguid%2F2410887629%2F3914928%3Ffwsitesection%3Dbrand_video_vod_embed%26form%3Dvars%26component%3Dplayer%26autoPlay%3Dtrue%26referrer%3Dfacebook">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://pdk.theplatform.com/current/pdk/swf/flvPlayer.swf?id=player&amp;v=%2F%2Fplayer.theplatform.com%2Fp%2FNnzsPC%2Fwidget%2Fconfig%2Fselect%2Fmedia%2Fguid%2F2410887629%2F3914928%3Ffwsitesection%3Dbrand_video_vod_embed%26form%3Dvars%26component%3Dplayer%26autoPlay%3Dtrue%26referrer%3Dfacebook">
<meta property="video:actor" content="Actor 1">
<meta property="video:actor" content="Actor 2">
<meta property="video:actor" content="Actor 3">
<meta property="video:actor" content="Actor 4">
<meta property="video:actor" content="Actor 5">
<meta property="video:actor" content="Actor 6">
<meta property="video:actor" content="Actor 7">
<meta property="video:actor" content="Actor 8">
<meta property="video:duration" content="2622">
<meta property="video:series" content="Show Name ">
<meta property="video:tag" content="Full Episode">
<meta property="video:release_date" content="2019-03-06T10:00:00.000Z">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="653521154659171">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="BRAND">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/url-of-video">
```

Comment: Do you have the correct namespace set, on your `<head>` tag, http://ogp.me/ns/video# ?

Comment: To add to Olivier's comment, you set the namespace like this `<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# video: http://ogp.me/ns/video#">`

Comment: I just checked, and neither of the pages - both the one that validated and te one that didn't - have the namespace included.

Comment: Yup, can confirm that og:type video.other also returns the same warning.